# Looking for link to Double Pole Single Throw (DPST) relay for Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

Need to find a DPST relay that is 'Arduino' friendly and that is capable of 30A at 240VAC. Anyone can share links ?

Not looking for recommendation, just ideas on what you saw or used in the past.

Thanks.

Comment: 30A is going to be a large relay. Get ready to put down a bit of cash.

Comment: cash is not an issue here, finding one that I can couple to an Arduino is...

Comment: I am maybe confused... The 240V circuit is composed of 2 live wires, 120V each, phased out by 90 degree to get the full 240Vac.

Comment: you could use a solid state relay ... it should work directly on the arduino

Comment: I use this: https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-SPDT-Relay%2830A%29-p-1473.html

Comment: @juraj How would you connect the 2 phase wires on that ?

Answer (score 1):

A relay that can switch 30A on mains voltage is not going to be able to switch directly from 5V. Getting something that can switch from 24V is much more realistic.

High amp relays are often called contactors. 4-pole ones are not uncommon for industrial motor applications. 3 high-amp poles are for 3-phase power and a low-amp one for a control signal.

You can buffer up the signal using a transistor (you'd need one anyway to supply the coil amps) or another relay.

Comment: Indeed and using an other relay to control the main relay is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do not be scared from other answers. There are relays which hold the coil with 5 V from Arduino. Like the relay on this [Grove 30 A Relay Module](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-SPDT-Relay%2830A%29-p-1473.html). It is powered from 5 V pin and the command to close is from the GPIO pin (works with 3.3V IO too).

Use two of these SPDT modules, if you can't find DPST powered with 5 V.

If you will use the Grove module and you do not use other Grove modules, there is no need to buy the Grove base shield. You can connect the module with [this cable.](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-4-pin-Male-Jumper-to-Grove-4-pin-Conversion-Cable-%285-PCs-per-Pack%29-p-1565.html)

Comment: The Grove module mentioned in this answer is only single pole. The question asks for a double pole relay.

Answer (score 0):

You will be hard-pressed to find a mechanical relay that you can directly connect to the Arduino digital pins. Any general purpose relay that fits your specs for the switched side will do, but you will need to pay attention to the datasheet for the coil voltage and current required to activate the relay.

Then, you'll want to use a driver circuit like a transistor (BJT or MOSFET) so that the low-voltage, low-current digital output of the Arduino can control the larger-current needed to trip the relay coil.

Comment: Yeah and opto isolation ;-)

Comment: A well designed relay driver circuit ought not strictly need opto-isolation. If you put a reverse-biased diode across the relay coils to prevent voltage spikes from damaging the transistor, the relay itself provides sufficient isolation between the switched circuit and the microcontroller.